# How to call shortcode in onclick href (in Html widget)?

Tags: wordpress, onclick, href, shortcode

I need to call shortcode [profile-url] when click Submit button.
I tried following codes, but they all don't call the url.

```
onclick="location.href='<?php echo do_shortcode('[profile-url]'); ?>';"
onclick="javascript:location.href='<?php echo do_shortcode('[profile-url]'); ?>';"
onclick="location.href=<?php echo  do_shortcode('#profile-url')?>;"
onclick="location.href='[profile-url]';"
onclick="location.href=<?php profile-url(); ?>;"
```

I tested this shortcode [profile-url] using Nav menu plugin and it works well.
It just doesn't work with my Menu code below.
Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Menu code in Elementor using Html widget:

```
<li>
    <a id="fourth-menu" class="menu">
      <h2 class="menu-title menu-title_4th">Myhome</h2>
      <ul id="menu-dropdown-four" class="menu-dropdown">
        <li onclick="location.href=????????????;">Submit</li>
        <li>Progress</li>
      </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

[profile-url] in Function.php (works well):

```
    add_shortcode( 'profile-url' , 'infosubmission_url' );
    function infosubmission_url(){
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
     
      if( !$user->ID ){
        //user not logged in, redirect to login package
        return ( 'www.myweb.com/project-login-required/' );
      }
     
      //User is logged in, return dynamic URL
      $username = $user->user_login;
      return ( 'www.myweb.com/mypage-infosubmit/' );
    }

//it allows you to use short code in menue link
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode'); 
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter( 'widget_html', 'do_shortcode');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this for testing

```
onclick="javascript:location.href=http://www.uol.com.br/"
```

and if it's working, please adjust the PHP code.

Update:

```php
    <li>
        <a id="fourth-menu" class="menu">
           <h2 class="menu-title menu-title_4th">Myhome</h2>
           <ul id="menu-dropdown-four" class="menu-dropdown">
           <?php
            $output = '<li onclick="' . do_shortcode('profile-url') .'">Submit</li>';
            echo $ouput;
            ?>
        <li>Progress</li>
      </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need to call shortcode [profile-url] , instead of a specific url. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Fioi
What I meant that is the missing "javascript" in the 
[onclick="javascript:location.href=http://www.uol.com.br/]
versus
[onclick="location.href=http://www.uol.com.br/"]. 
So you can do this with just this code: 
onclick="javascript:location.href='<?php echo do_shortcode('[profile-url]'); ?>'

Comment: oh, sorry, I tried the code, but the button doesn't react when I click it...

Comment: @Fioi
1)Please try the new updated code in the answer if it's working for you. 
2) You should not use <a> tag to wrap those ul, li element. It's not recommended.

Comment: I updated codes, and the menu code is based on this => https://codepen.io/kkrueger/pen/qfoLa

Comment: So is this code working for you? I meant the 
<?php
            $output = '<li onclick="' . do_shortcode('profile-url') .'">Submit</li>';
            echo $ouput;
            ?>

Comment: Hi Tony: Thanks for your help. I tried the code but it says 'Expected tag name. Got '?' instead. HTML doesn't support processing instructions.' My Menu code is located in Elementor using Html widge. Sorry, I'm a newbie, very culmsy ...

Comment: And, [profile-url] shows relevant url when I put the shortcode in a Text widget after I put => add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode'); in function.php. It just doesn’t work when I put it in the HTML widget, although I put => add_filter( 'widget_html', 'do_shortcode');. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: For custom html you will need to use 2 add_filter
----
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop'); 
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
---
Then you could use the shortcode in custom html.

Comment: Hi Tony: thank you for your supportive help. I changed HTML widget in Elementor and it works now. Thank you again : )